# Updating UITableView will cause exception

Tags: iphone, exception

I have `UITableViewController` subclassed and implemented the following

1. `NSFetchedResultsController` with its delegates
2. `tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex:`
3. `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:`

In `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:`

```
case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
           withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
           withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    break;
```

In data model for the given entity I have transient property `uppercaseFirstLetterOfName` which will return first letter of persistent property.

This is all to achieve Alphabetical sections for table items and side index.

Now if I have a single record for a section, then I rename it so it will change the section, I get the following exception, which happens somewhere after `NSFetchedResultsChangeMove`.

> *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-984.38/UITableView.m:774
>
> Exception was caught during Core Data
>   change processing: Invalid update:
>   invalid number of rows in section 0. 
>   The number of rows contained in an
>   existing section after the update (1)
>   must be equal to the number of rows
>   contained in that section before the
>   update (1), plus or minus the number
>   of rows inserted or deleted from that
>   section (0 inserted, 1 deleted).

Any ideas?

UPD some more code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
    NSInteger count = [[fetchedResultsController sections] count];
    return count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
                         numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    NSInteger numberOfRows = 0;
    if ([[fetchedResultsController sections] count] > 0) 
    {
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo =
              [[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
        numberOfRows = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    }
    return numberOfRows;
}
```

...

```
    NSSortDescriptor* sortByWordDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] 
                        initWithKey:@"subject" ascending:YES];
    NSArray* sortArray = [[NSArray alloc]
                        initWithObjects:sortByWordDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortArray];

    NSFetchedResultsController* controller = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                        initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
                        managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext 
                        sectionNameKeyPath:@"uppercaseFirstLetterOfName" 
                        cacheName:@"Root"];
```

UPD(patched):
At the moment I patched the code like this:

```
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
        NSUInteger tableSectionCount = [self.tableView numberOfSections];
        NSUInteger modelSectionCount = [[controller sections] count];
        if (modelSectionCount > tableSectionCount) 
        {
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet
                                indexSetWithIndex:[newIndexPath section]]
                                withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        }
        else if(modelSectionCount < tableSectionCount)
        {
            if (tableSectionCount > 1) 
            {
                [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet
                                 indexSetWithIndex:[indexPath section]] 
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            }
        }
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray
                                 arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray
                                 arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] 
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        break;
```

So far no crash, but is this correct solution?

Comment: I guess `NSFetchedResultsController` does not know that the section is deleted, since `controller:didChangeSection:...` never fires. But how to handle this?

Comment: According to traces, after the object is modified and as a result the number of sections should be decreased, actually `[[fetchedResultsController sections] count]` returns an old value. So how to update controller's section count or invalidate transient property?

Answer (score 2):

I think I know what's happening to you. Make sure you have:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

The documentation says about "beginUpdates" method:

> Call this method if you want subsequent insertions, deletion, and selection operations (for example, cellForRowAtIndexPath: and indexPathsForVisibleRows) to be animated simultaneously.

which is what you're doing with:

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The code that handles the sections is going to expect an item to be at a certain index but that item is no longer there and it doesn't seem you have coded for that scenario by returning nil when there's no item there.

Comment: Could you you please be more specific? Which code is going to expect, mine or framework's? Where should I return nil?

Answer (score 0):

you should modify the datasource array before do any insert or delete method of tableView!

```
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

and `NSFetchedResultsChangeMove` should finish your UI movement action.
so what you need do is to reorder the datasorce items.

Comment: check live demo codes here:
http://github.com/erica/iphone-3.0-cookbook-/blob/master/C11-Tables/13-Enabling%20Reordering/main.m

Comment: Reorder the datasource items? I'm not sure if I understand how would I do that. In this controller I just pass an object from `fetchedResultsController` to other view controller, where it's modified and at that time the delegates of `NSFetchedResultsController` are fired. The demo codes don't use `NSFetchedResultsController`, so I can't figure out...

Comment: As a matter of fact, using `NSFetchedResultsController` makes datasource modifications first, then calling `didChangeObject` to update data table. Still confused and looking for solution.